# MongoDB - keep document fields/values based on a required fields array stored in document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Original question**

In MongoDB, I have documents of the type:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000001"),
  "a": {"a_1":  11, "a_2":  22},
  "b": {"b_1":  111, "b_2":  222},
  "c": {"c_1":  1, "c_2":  2},
  "anomalies": ["a", "b"]
}, 
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000002"),
  "a": {"a_1":  11, "a_2":  22},
  "d": {"d_1":  222, "d_2":  333},
  "e": {"e_1":  1, "e_2":  2},
  "anomalies": ["a", "d"]
}
```

I want to write a query which returns all documents in the DB (for the sake of the example), but only keeping the document fields specified in the `anomalies` array. I know that there is a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator which I can use, but as I understand it, I need to specify each value which I want to project. In my case, these values are contained in the `anomalies` array and could thus be different for each document.

How can I achieve this with the Aggregation Framework? If impossible, what are alternative ways of solving the problem?

**Update**
A clarification based on the comments: in each document, the values present in the `anomalies` array are guaranteed to be found as fields of the respective document.

Comment: array anomalies will only have values a,b,c or can be any alphabets? and we have to fetch only anomalies with values of a,b,c in array anomalies right ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you right, but: it is guaranteed that the elements of the anomalies array will also be found as document keys, so in the provided example there could be no 'd' or 'd123' in anomalies, since it is not a field of the document.

Comment: so anomalies array can have non-existant key as its value, in that case what will be returned considering anomalies have value "d" but d key does not exists in the document.

Comment: no, it can not. I edited the question to reflect your comments and hopefully clarify the state of affairs.

Comment: Is there any fixed limit of values the array anomalies can have?

Comment: Theoretically each field of the document could be an anomaly, so the array size would be the number of fields - 1 (_id). But this cannot be known beforehand, since the documents can have different number of fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in a single pipeline stage. Use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) and [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) to manipulate the root of your document, [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to match keys against `anomalies` array and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote result to root level:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
                        cond: {
                            $in: [ "$$this.k", "$anomalies" ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

EDIT: you can also use [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) to include `_id`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                    { _id: "$_id" },
                    {
                        $arrayToObject: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
                                cond: {
                                    $in: [ "$$this.k", "$anomalies" ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nTt71b-0D3O)